# App crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x0)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9

I know that there is a lot of such questions so I try to provide as many details a possible. I have game developed with SpriteKit and several scenes. When I do transition from one scene to another I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x0)`.

With `bt` I have this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x70119f, 0x0000000107e173b0 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 112, queue = 'com.apple.spritekit.renderQueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000107e173b0 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 112
    frame #1: 0x0000000103c4ce8c SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 1156
    frame #2: 0x0000000103c4d9a9 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 4001
    frame #3: 0x0000000103c4d9a9 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 4001
    frame #4: 0x0000000103c4d9a9 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 4001
    frame #5: 0x0000000103c46da1 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessAndSubmitSpriteInternal(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo const*, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo const*> >&, std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&) + 139
    frame #6: 0x0000000103c4a951 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::submitScene(SKScene*, bool) + 393
    frame #7: 0x0000000103c4853c SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::renderTransition(SKScene*, SKScene*, float) + 952
    frame #8: 0x0000000103be6ece SpriteKit`-[SKView _renderContent] + 847
    frame #9: 0x0000000107abd614 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #10: 0x0000000107aa3002 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
    frame #11: 0x0000000103be6a80 SpriteKit`-[SKView renderContent] + 96
    frame #12: 0x0000000103be3a61 SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 56
    frame #13: 0x0000000103c0f744 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 256
    frame #14: 0x00000001068a310f QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 37
    frame #15: 0x00000001068a2fd7 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 315
    frame #16: 0x0000000102f9c174 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    frame #17: 0x0000000102f9bd35 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    frame #18: 0x0000000102f5dd3d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    frame #19: 0x0000000102f5d366 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #20: 0x0000000106e88a3e GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #21: 0x0000000103d808c0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
  * frame #22: 0x0000000102a0628d MemoryGame`main + 109 at AppDelegate.swift:15
    frame #23: 0x0000000107af1145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Maybe it is important: in next scene `didMoveToView` I preload textures (several atlases).

Update #1

I enabled address sanitizer and now it crashes inside it:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x705cf2, 0x000000010e36c0b0 libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`__sanitizer::internal_memmove(void*, void const*, unsigned long) + 320, queue = 'com.apple.spritekit.renderQueue', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x460)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010e36c0b0 libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`__sanitizer::internal_memmove(void*, void const*, unsigned long) + 320
    frame #1: 0x000000010e3505a7 libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_memcpy + 1095
    frame #2: 0x0000000110119e8c SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 1156
    frame #3: 0x000000011011a9a9 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 4001
    frame #4: 0x000000011011a9a9 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 4001
    frame #5: 0x000000011011a9a9 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool) + 4001
    frame #6: 0x0000000110113da1 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::preprocessAndSubmitSpriteInternal(std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo const*, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo const*> >&, std::__1::vector<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo, std::__1::allocator<SKCRenderer::SpriteRenderInfo> >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&) + 139
    frame #7: 0x0000000110117951 SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::submitScene(SKScene*, bool) + 393
    frame #8: 0x000000011011553c SpriteKit`SKCRenderer::renderTransition(SKScene*, SKScene*, float) + 952
    frame #9: 0x00000001100b3ece SpriteKit`-[SKView _renderContent] + 847
    frame #10: 0x0000000113f8a614 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #11: 0x0000000113f70002 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365
    frame #12: 0x00000001100b3a80 SpriteKit`-[SKView renderContent] + 96
    frame #13: 0x00000001100b0a61 SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 56
    frame #14: 0x00000001100dc744 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 256
    frame #15: 0x0000000112d7010f QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 37
    frame #16: 0x0000000112d6ffd7 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 315
    frame #17: 0x000000010f469174 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    frame #18: 0x000000010f468d35 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    frame #19: 0x000000010f42ad3d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    frame #20: 0x000000010f42a366 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #21: 0x0000000113355a3e GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #22: 0x000000011024d8c0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
    frame #23: 0x000000010e1a928d MemoryGame`main + 109 at AppDelegate.swift:15
    frame #24: 0x0000000113fbe145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #25: 0x0000000113fbe145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: Did you try using address sanitizer ?

Comment: @Dudi I updated my question with address sanitizer trace.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add a `particleEmitter` to the first scene? Do you use the `.targetNode` property of that `particleEmitter`?

If so, I had that very same problem. There seems to be a bug in SpriteKit that needs you to manually set that `.targetNode` property to `nil` before changing the scene. Try `particleEmitter?.targetNode = nil` in a `deinit` function or similar...

In my case, I used `targetNode` just to make the particles of an emitter appear on top of the background, but you can get the same behavior using the `.zPosition` and `.particleZPosition` properties of the emitter (I set both properties to a number higher than the `.zPosition` of the background object) thus avoiding the use of `targetNode`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: No, I don't use emitter at any of my scenes.

Comment: Then I cannot help you, sorry. I'm not good at reading `bt` outputs. :(